# How to reuse a serializer in Django (Python)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a service in a Django app that I am building where I want to handle get and post requests. I though I should reuse a serializer I've built but in the examples I found, whenever someone wants to use a serializer they create a new object.

This is an implementation where the serializer class is called multiple times to create multiple instances, one each time a request arrives:

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.http.request import RAISE_ERROR, HttpRequest
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework import status
from models import Instrument
from serializers import InstrumentsSerializer

class InstrumentsService():

    def __init__(self):
        self.serializer: InstrumentsSerializer = None

    def get_instruments_by_type(self, instrument_type: str):
        if instrument_type is not None:
            instruments = Instrument.objects.all()
            instruments.filter(instrument_type__icontains=instrument_type)
            instruments_serializer = InstrumentsSerializer(instruments, many=True)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Value type None is not acceptable for 'instrument_type'")

        return instruments_serializer.data

    def add_instrument(self, instrument_data: Instrument):
        instrument_serializer = InstrumentsSerializer(data=instrument_data)

        if instrument_serializer.is_valid():
            instrument_serializer.save()
```

How can I use the same serializer and pass different data to it each time? Because in the example I presented, the data are being passed during initialization.

Comment: You can't. Serializers accept data only during initialization. You can't pass new data to a Serializer object.

Comment: damned it! Ok thanks

Comment: Why don't you use serializers.ModelSerializer from rest_framework?

Comment: @EliasPrado I am using it. The InstrumentSerializer is s serializer that I made and it inherits from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use Python [Class Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)?

```
class InstrumentsService():
    serializer = InstrumentsSerializer 

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_instruments_by_type(self, instrument_type: str):
        if instrument_type is not None:
            instruments = Instrument.objects.all()
            instruments.filter(instrument_type__icontains=instrument_type)
            instruments_serializer = InstrumentsService.serializer(instruments, many=True)
```

Comment: but the initialization will only happen once no? How can I pass a new set of data to serialize? The problem is that the data to be serialized are passed on initialization.

Comment: like if I initialize it in the get method then how am I gonna pas the data I want in the add method, or in a subsequent call of the get method? I ll still have to create new instances each time

Comment: A serializer is always used that way that you pass the data to the constructor. It does not make sense to instantiate an 'empty' serializer and later fill it with data. The serialization is done during construction of the object. If you look at this basic example https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#example you'll also see that the serializer is defined as a Class Object inside the ModelViewSet.

Comment: I know but I thought maybe you can manipulate the  object somehow to accept data after initialization. Anyway thanks.